# Why can't I add objects to my List<>?

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I have a class, clsPerson, that looks like this:

```
public class clsPerson
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    public string Gender;
    public List<Book> Books;
}
```

I have another class, Book, that looks like this:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title;
    public string Author;
    public string Genre;        

    public Book(string title, string author, string genre)
    {            
        this.Title = title;
        this.Author = author;
        this.Genre = genre;
    }
}
```

I wrote a program to test serializing an object into XML.  Here's what I have, so far:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new clsPerson();
        p.FirstName = "Kevin";            
        p.LastName = "Jennings";
        p.Gender = "Male";

        var book1 = new Book("Neuromancer", "William Gibson", "Science Fiction");
        var book2 = new Book("The Hobbit", "J.R.R. Tolkien", "Fantasy");
        var book3 = new Book("Rendezvous with Rama", "Arthur C. Clarke", "Science Fiction");

        p.Books.Add(book1);
        p.Books.Add(book2);
        p.Books.Add(book3);

        var x = new XmlSerializer(p.GetType());

        x.Serialize(Console.Out, p);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error, though, in VS2013 that says "NullReferenceException was unhandled" on line `p.Books.Add(book1);`.

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong.  I thought that I could create a few books and then add them to my `clsPerson` object's `List` called `Books`.  I can't figure out why the error is saying 'NullReferenceException' when the `book1` object was just instantiated prior to me trying to add it to my `Books` list.  Can someone offer me a pointer or some advice?

Comment: Generally clsPerson is a VB style naming convention; in C# you'd just use Person as the class name. Not to mention your naming conventions aren't consistent amongst your other classes. At least pick one consistent style of naming classes. Preferably the C# way :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should initialize your list first:

```
if(p.Books == null)
   p.Books = new List<Book>();
```

It is more appropriate to do it in your `clsPerson` class constructor.

Comment: Argh!  Thanks so much!  I'll mark this as the answer as soon as the timer is up.

Comment: also to serialize you need an empty constructor for book

Answer (score 8):

You are not instantiating your Books collection in your `Person` class

In your Person constructor:

```
public Person()
{
  this.Books = new List<Book>();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should really initialize your objects when creating them in a `class`.

Try this:

```
public class clsPerson
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    public string Gender;
    public List<Book> Books = new List<Book>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I did exactly this with the help of the Selman22's answer above.  He beat out Cam Bruce by three seconds with his answer, but they both suggested that I initialize the list in the person constructor, which I've done so now.  Thanks again, though!

Comment: @KevinJ Doing this in the constructor is not really the best method. Just imagine if you had 2 or 3 constructors :) As a general rule, initialize at the variable deceleration to lower the risk of `NullReferenceExceptions`